# 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'diff'

Tags: python, numpy, ta-lib

I'm trying this snippet (from web) in my script which calculates StochRSI.

The error output I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user2\PycharmProjects\xxx2\main.py", line 99, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\user2\PycharmProjects\xxx2\main.py", line 87, in main
    stoch_rsi = StochRSI(closing_data)
  File "C:\Users\user2\PycharmProjects\xxx2\main.py", line 56, in StochRSI
    delta = series.diff().dropna()
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'diff'
```

Tried searching for answers but couldn't find any to fix the problem. What's wrong here?

EDIT: Please check the full code below. I hope it clears out what I'm doing... I used numpy to get closing prices. I used that to get live EMA, and it worked fine - and now I'm trying to get StochRSI's live value.

```
import datetime
import config
import csv
import os.path
import sys
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import requests
import talib

from binance.client import Client
from binance.enums import *

from time import sleep

def get_data():
    historical_data = client.get_historical_klines(symbol=config.SYMBOL, interval=config.TIME_PERIOD, start_str="1 year ago UTC", klines_type=HistoricalKlinesType.SPOT)

    return_data = []

    for each in historical_data:
        kline = float(each[4])

        return_data.append(kline)

    return np.array(return_data)

def StochRSI(series, period=14, smoothK=3, smoothD=3):
    # Calculate RSI
    delta = series.diff().dropna()
    ups = delta * 0
    downs = ups.copy()
    ups[delta > 0] = delta[delta > 0]
    downs[delta < 0] = -delta[delta < 0]
    ups[ups.index[period-1]] = np.mean(ups[:period]) #first value is sum of avg gains
    ups = ups.drop(ups.index[:(period-1)])
    downs[downs.index[period-1]] = np.mean(downs[:period]) #first value is sum of avg losses
    downs = downs.drop(downs.index[:(period-1)])
    rs = ups.ewm(com=period-1, min_periods=0, adjust=False, ignore_na=False).mean() / \
         downs.ewm(com=period-1, min_periods=0, adjust=False, ignore_na=False).mean()
    rsi = 100 - 100 / (1 + rs)

    # Calculate StochRSI
    stochrsi = (rsi - rsi.rolling(period).min()) / (rsi.rolling(period).max() - rsi.rolling(period).min())
    stochrsi_K = stochrsi.rolling(smoothK).mean()
    stochrsi_D = stochrsi_K.rolling(smoothD).mean()

    return stochrsi, stochrsi_K, stochrsi_D

def main():
    ema_200 = None
    last_ema_200 = None

    while True:
        closing_data = get_data()
        last_candle = closing_data[-1]

        ema_200 = talib.EMA(closing_data, 10)[-1]
        stoch_rsi = StochRSI(closing_data)

        if last_candle > ema_200:
            print(f"Price {last_candle} is above EMA 200 {ema_200} | RSI {stoch_rsi}")
        elif last_candle < ema_200:
            print(f"Price {last_candle} is below EMA 200 {ema_200} | RSI {stoch_rsi}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Client
    client = Client(config.API_KEY, config.API_SECRET_KEY, tld='com')
    print(f"Authenticated")

    main()
```

Comment: `series` is numpy array, but your code looks like it expects Pandas dataframe or some sort of series?

Comment: I'm not sure...

Comment: I did it wrong I guess. I inserted "closing_data" to call that function. I thought that meant taking closing prices.

Comment: there is nothing to be "sure", it is a fact, and it is stated in the error :)

Comment: I have closing data, but how do I use this StochRSI function to get those values out if it...?

Comment: again - you are passing wrong **data type**. closing_data is **numpy array** and your function expects pandas.Series. Just convert it to the right type

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ultragtx/6831eb04dfe9e6ff50d0f334bdcb847d this is the link I used the code from. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong. I don't have "pandas" import in my python file.

Comment: This is not how python works. You do not have to "import pandas" to write code that expects pandas. It uses ducktyping - it calls functions (.diff(), .dropna(), .rolling()) that are implemented for pandas.Series and definitely are not for numpy. To reverse your argument - there is no import numpy, why are you expecting numpy array to be passable then?

Comment: I have numpy imported... "import numpy as np"

Comment: I will pause here as you do not seem to read the comments/answer provided by jss367 below.

Comment: You can't just grab a some code from the web, and expect to run it without actually understanding what it's doing.  When you get an `attribute error`, either the attribute is wrong (numpy arrays don't have a `diff` method), or the object is wrong.  Others think `series` should be a `pandas` dataframe.

Comment: I'm a novice :( How do I get to use pandas or numpy to make that function work? I updated my post with code on how I get data using numpy.

Comment: If you are borrowing someone elsss code, you should ask them first.  Or at least study their explanations and comments.

Answer (score 1):

This function is expecting a pandas `DataFrame` or `Series` but is getting a numpy `ndarray`.

Comment: How do I use numpy ndarray with this?

Comment: You have a couple options. One is to update the function to work with a numpy array. The other is to update the datatype to work with the function. I would have guessed that the function is already what you want, so I would guess you need to update the input datatype.

Comment: Yeah, so how do I use numpy ndarray with this function? Sorry for being too novice...

Comment: I updated my post and edited it with how I get my data.

Comment: OK. This is going to be hard to do because it depends on exactly what the data looks like. In general, you can convert a numpy array to a pandas Series with `series = pd.Series(array)`, but without knowing exactly what the data looks like, it's unlikely that everything will work out perfectly.

Comment: For example, the first thing you do in the function is clean the data. Is this necessary for your data? The chances that this function does exactly what you want for your case is low. My suggestion would be to walk through the function line by line and make sure you understand every step.

Comment: I updated the post with full code. Please check.